# Copy if range of cells is full

Tags: excel, vba

I try to copy the data if any part of the range has values, otherwise do nothing.

I think that when I set the variable `consulRng` I am not doing it correctly and it does not determine if it is full or not, it always makes the copy.

```
Sub BlankLine()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim consulRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkRng = Range("A:E")
    Set consulRng = Worksheets("Hoja 2").Range("J2:O2")
    xLastRow = WorkRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    If IsEmpty(consulRng) Then
        GoTo EndSub
    Else:
        For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step -1
        Set Rng = WorkRng.Range("A" & xRowIndex)
            If Rng.Value = "Esto es una prueba" Then
                Sheets("Hoja 2").Range("H2:O2").Copy
                Rng.Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Rng.Offset(1, 0).Paste
            End If
        Next
            
    End If
    
    Application.CutMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
EndSub:
End Sub
```

Updated code:

```
Sub BlankLine()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim consulRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkRng = Range("A:E")
    Set consulRng = Worksheets("Hoja 2").Range("J2:O2")
    xLastRow = WorkRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'If Not IsEmpty(consulRng) Then
    'If Application.CountA(consulRng) = 0 Then
    If Not Application.Count(consulRng) = 0 Then 'Contribution: PEH
        For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step -1
        Set Rng = WorkRng.Range("A" & xRowIndex)
            If Rng.Value = "Esto es una prueba" Then
                Sheets("Hoja 2").Range("H2:O2").Copy
                Rng.Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Rng.Offset(1, 0).Paste
            End If
        Next
            
    End If
    
    Application.CutMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Hoja1:

[image: Hoja1]

Hoja2:

[image: Hoja2]

Hoja2Datacomplete:

[image: Hoja2Datacomplete]

Hoja1Datacomplete:

[image: Hoja1Datanocomplete]

Comment: First remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides **all** error messages, but the errors still occur, you just cannot see their messages. If you don't see your errors you cannot fix them, if you don't fix them your code does not work as expected. Remove that line and fix your errors, if you gets stuck tell where and which error you get. • Don't use `GoTo` (that'? a very bad practice) you can use `If Not IsEmpty(consulRng) Then` and remove the `GoTo EndSub` and `Else:`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ You are absolutely right, I get a '438' error - Object does not support this property or method in: Rng.Offset(1, 0).Paste

However, it still copies the values even if the range of fields is empty.

Comment: You need to insert first then copy then paste, or just remove the paste. If you copy before insert the copied range will be inserted instead of an empty space (so no need to paste then).

Comment: `If Application.CountA(consulRng) =0 Then`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ So far the execution in that part has been correct....

You have inserted a new row below the cell containing: "This is a test" and copied the other cells.

The problem is that it always copies the range, but I only want it to copy it if the range J2:02 is filled.

Comment: @TimWilliams No, it didn't work, it's still doing the same as before.

Comment: What does *"if the range J2:02 is filled"* exactly mean? If at least one of those cells has data or if **all** of those cells have data?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yes, sorry, it would be that it meets this condition: If at least one of those cells has data in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IsEmpty function doesn't work the way you are thinking. It doesn't look in the values of the range to determine if there is data but rather checks if the variable has been assigned yet. I went ahead and made a hasData() function that will do the trick. Also, I removed a few lines that were giving me errors.

```
Sub BlankLine2()
    Dim Rng As range
    Dim WorkRng As range
    Dim consulRng As range
    'On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkRng = range("A:E")
    Set consulRng = Worksheets("Hoja 2").range("J2:O2")
    xLastRow = range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    If Not hasData(consulRng) Then
        For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step -1
        Set Rng = WorkRng.range("A" & xRowIndex)
            If Rng.Value = "Esto es una prueba" Then
                Sheets("Hoja 2").range("H2:O2").Copy
                Rng.Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If
        Next
            
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function hasData(r) As Boolean
    For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            hasData = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cell
    hasData = True
End Function
```

**Edit with additional functionality as requested in comments below**
The below code will continue inserting the data until it reaches a blank row. It will also paste as value removing any formulas.

```
Sub BlankLine4()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim consulRng As Range
    
    xLastRow1 = Worksheets("Hoja 1").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    xLastRow2 = Worksheets("Hoja 2").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    
    
    For xSheet2RowIndex = xLastRow2 To 2 Step -1
        Set copyRng = Worksheets("Hoja 2").Range("H" & xSheet2RowIndex & ":O" & xSheet2RowIndex)
        Set consulRng = Worksheets("Hoja 2").Range("J" & xSheet2RowIndex & ":O" & xSheet2RowIndex)
        If hasData(consulRng) Then
            For xRowIndex = xLastRow1 To 1 Step -1
                Set Rng = Worksheets("Hoja 1").Range("A:E").Range("A" & xRowIndex)
                If Rng.Value = "Esto es una prueba" Then
                    Rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    copyRng.Copy
                    Rng.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                End If
            Next
        End If
        
    Next xSheet2RowIndex
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function hasData(r) As Boolean
'Checks to see if any cells or formula results are non-blank
    For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            hasData = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cell
    hasData = False
End Function
```

Comment: Why a loop if you can solve it without? Loops are always slow.

Comment: How could I have this command repeated for each of the values in columns H and I from H2:I2?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you mean you would like to insert 2 rows? One for H2 + data and one for I2 + data?

Comment: Forgive me if I did not express myself well. On "Sheet 2" there is a table, with combined cells: H-I, J-K, L-M, N-O. Inside the "column": H:I, I have different values and I would like to know if it is possible to apply this operation on all its values, until there is no more data.

I hope I have explained myself.

Comment: I have another question, when I try to enter a formula, it copies the whole formula and loses the references, can it copy only the values?

Comment: Take a look at the code above. I think this will work but it will stop when it hits a row with no data. Is it possible you may have a blank row and then more data afterwards?

Comment: It didn't work and completely froze my Excel.

Comment: My apologies! I think I found the reason you results weren't accurate and resolved it. As for the speed, may I ask about how many times "Esto es una prueba" appears? And how long is this list of values we want to insert?

Comment: Also, are these two tables both on "Hoja 2"?

Comment: In inserted in the question two screenshots, right above

Comment: When I tested the code once again I saw what you asked me about the blanks and yes, there can be... I'm sorry I didn't tell you before.

I add screenshots to the question.

Comment: The screenshots were very helpful! Thank you. I edited my post and it works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't get to tell you anything, sorry.

Comment: @BenMega I have a question with this new code, it works perfect but I don't know if I'm not doing it right or if something has changed...

Comment: So is it working or not? If not, can you explain what is off?

Comment: Good morning,

Sorry for the ambiguity. Yes, it works, but since all the cells contain a formula, which is the one that counts specific values, it copies all the rows.

Comment: Sorry, based on your response to Peh's solution I assumed you didn't have formulas. I have reverted my solution to using the HasData function which will exclude formulas pulling in blanks.

Comment: Sorry, thank you very much for your new reply.
I was forced a posteriori to enter formulas in the cells.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
If Not IsEmpty(consulRng) Then
```

just

```
If Not Application.CountA(consulRng) = 0 Then
```

Comment: Modifying the line you mentioned did not work. :(

Comment: does the range contain formulas? If yes, are the results numeric or text?

Comment: I knew there had to be a better way! This replaces the function I wrote fine for me. There also are a few lines that need to be removed as well to stop the errors, though.

Comment: No, not at the moment. They only have numerical values. The solution indicated by BenMega has worked.

Comment: If they are numeric then `Count` instead of `CountA` should work too. `Count` gives you the amount of cells that have numeric data. That should definitly work or something really strange is happening there. Make sure you use the `Not`! • If it still does not work please give the result of `Debug.Print Application.CountA(consulRng)` and  `Debug.Print Application.Count(consulRng)`

Comment: I show you the code with your contribution in: Updated code

Comment: Sorry, it does work. I must have put something wrong. What BenMega described is much faster.

But thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Ahh, yes I assumed that, would be strange if it would not work. Are you sure the loop is quicker than counting? Cannot believe that.

Comment: Yes, the loop does it in milliseconds and as written with the modifications it takes a few seconds.

Comment: That's pretty strange.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that loops over your range and checks if any cell is not empty:

```
Function IsEmptyRange(rCells As Range) As Boolean
    IsEmptyRange = True
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In rCells
        If r <> vbNullString Then
            IsEmptyRange = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

Then, instead of `If Not IsEmpty(consulRng) Then` you can use your function `If Not IsEmptyRange(Sheet1.Range("a1:a5")) Then`

When copying and pasting I suggest to use `.PasteSpecial` and you can choose the paste type here, e.g. xlPasteAll, xlPasteValues etc.

Comment: Beat me by 10 seconds!

Comment: Why a loop if you can solve it without? Loops are always slow.

Comment: I agree that in this case your solution is the best, but it was just my idea, not perfect :)